# docker invalid characters for local volume name

Tags: docker, docker-compose

A few days ago, I installed docker on my new laptop. I've used docker for a while and know the basics pretty well. Yet, for some reason I keep bumping into the same problem and I hope someone here can help me.

After installing the Docker Toolbox on my Windows 10 Home laptop, I tried to run some images that I've created using a docker-compose.yml. Since my user directory on windows has my exact name in it (C:/Users/Nick van der Meij) and that name contains spaces, I added an extra shared folder from C:/code to /mnt/code on the Docker Host (this works). I've used [this](http://developmentalmadness.com/2016/03/05/docker-permanently-mount-a-virtualbox-shared-folder/) guide to do so

However, when I try to run my docker-compose.yml (included below), I get the following error:

```
ERROR: for php  Cannot create container for service php: create \mnt\code\basic_php\api: "\\mnt\\code\\basic_php\\api" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed
[31mERROR[0m: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

As far as I see it, everything seems to be correct according to the official docker docs about volumes. I've spend many hours trying to fix this and tried out multiple "formats" for the volumes tag, yet without any success.

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Thanks in Advance!

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
    mysql:
        image: mysql:5.7
        ports:
            - 3306
        volumes:
            - /var/lib/mysql
        restart: always
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
            MYSQL_USER: user
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
            MYSQL_DATABASE: database
    nginx:
        image: nginx:1.10.2
        ports:
            - 80:80
            - 443:443
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - /mnt/code/basic_php/nginx/conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
            - /mnt/code/basic_php/api:/code/api
            - /mnt/code/basic_php/nginx:/code/nginx
        links:
            - php
            - site
        depends_on:
            - php
            - site
    php:
        build: php
        expose:
            - 9000
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - /mnt/code/basic_php/php/conf/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/custom.ini
            - /mnt/code/basic_php/api:/code/api
        links:
            - mysql
    site:
        restart: always
        build: site
        ports:
            - 80
        container_name: site
```

Comment: Is the error exactly in this Line ?
     - /mnt/code/basic_php/api:/code/api
Have you commented it out ?
What happens if you switch the two volumes in php

Comment: the error persist on all the volume lines in all the containers (nginx and php)

Comment: UPDATE: without volumes, the containers do run correctly, however this is not the desired end result (i need the volumes for mounting config and source code)

Comment: So maybe it is a Windows Problem with Slashes und Backslashes

Comment: Might be so, doing everything manually from the docker host atm using the docker-machine ssh command atm which is quite annoying. If any1 has a solution to this problem please let me know =D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a few hours searching the web, I finally found what i was looking for. Like Wolfgang Blessen said in the comments below my question, the problem was indeed a Windows Path problem.

If you dont want docker to automatically convert paths windows to unix, you need to add the COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS environment variable with a value of 0 like explained here: [link](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#/composeconvertwindowspaths)

Comment: Thanks for digging this up!
To be more explicit, this is what worked for me:
`export COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1`
`docker-compose up --build -d`
(note: the specific options to docker-compose are not relevant)
Environment: git-bash under Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

Use git bash and do

```
export COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1
```

then execute

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Answer (score 0):

Or simply use double backslash

```
winpty docker run -it -v C:\\path\\to\\folder:/mount
```