# Docker Toolbox Windows - Invalid volume specification

Tags: docker-compose

**EDIT:** The problem is the `COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS` environment variable isn't getting set. I tried adding it to the `Dockerfile` and to a `.env` file but its not being set. I can't set any new environment variables. Its like its building it from a cached Dockerfile.

I was running `docker-composer up` after deleting the container, but this didn't recreate a new container, even when adding `--force-recreate`, it created the container from the old Dockerfile. So I ran `docker build ./` instead, and it built a new container, it reinstalled all the packages, and it said that it was setting the new environment variables, but in the finished container, when I check kinematic, I see the new environment variables aren't set. But all of the old environment variables that were set when I built the container for the first time, they're all set. I don't know why this is happening, why I can't create a new container from the updated Dockerfile.

I've found a number of threads about this error, it happens when trying to mount a volume in Windows docker-tools. When I run `docker-compose up`, I get this error:

```
ERROR: for web  Cannot create container for service web: Invalid bind mount spec "C:\\path\\to\\project:/app:rw": Invalid volume specification: 'C:\path\to\project:/app:rw'
[31mERROR[0m: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

In the `docker-compose` file I have this:

```
    volumes:
        - ./:/app
```

I tried setting this environment variable:

```
COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1
```

to 1, as that worked for some people in another thread but its not working in this case. I tried adding an absolute path in linux like format:

```
    volumes:
        - /c/path/to/project:/app
```

and I get this error:

```
ERROR: for web  Cannot create container for service web: create \c\path\to\project: "\\c\\path\\to\\project" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed
```

Notice it reversed the forward slashes. Changing:

```
ENV COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=0
```

to 0 like that didn't change anything.

If I give a Windows format absolute directory, I get the first error again. Both of those errors, I get them if I point to a directory that doesn't exist.

Has anyone here figured out a way to resolve this?

Comment: When after setting the COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS environment variable I'd got the same error, I used /c/path/to/project:/app in Docker Terminal and it worked!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [docker invalid characters for local volume name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41394822/docker-invalid-characters-for-local-volume-name)

Answer (score 3):

So, if this problem exists, you should create new Windows environment variable called COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS and set it to 1. Or you can create .env file in the path docker-compose.yml is placed with following content:

```
 COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1
```

..

```
cat >.env
COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1` environment variable is not read by docker cli (powershell). you can try to run `Get-childItem Env:` command from your powershell console to get the list of environment variable which has been set in your powershell console. the output is like below:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS  1
COMSPEC                        C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
DOCKER_CERT_PATH               C:\Users\devsa\.docker\machine\machines\default
DOCKER_HOST                    tcp://192.168.99.100:2376
DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY              1
...
```

If you don't see the `COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1` variable in your powershell console, it means the variable has not been set yet. To set the environment variable via powershell console, try this command:

`$env:COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1`

it will set the environment variable in your power shell console [check this powershell documentation for full documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730964.aspx). Try to run the `Get-childItem Env:` command again to check whether the variable has been already set or not. if the variable has been set, you can try to run `docker-compose up -d` again.

Answer (score 0):

After setting the environment variable to COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1 try below setting in docker-compose

```
- ./app-demo:/dockermount under volumes
```

It worked for me